# Change usage text in Snakemake workflow catalog

Tags: snakemake

How would one change the usage text for a workflow in the [Snakemake workflow catalog](https://snakemake.github.io/snakemake-workflow-catalog/?usage=snakemake-workflows)?
[image]

[image]

For the example I have shown, I have been through all the directories in the [repository](https://github.com/snakemake-workflows/rna-seq-star-deseq2), but I cannot find a file that has that text.

I would like to change this text for my own workflow that I have submitted.

Comment: It seems like the Workflow is from the repo name, the Description and Topics are from the about section in the repo (on the top right), and QC seems to be run by the workflow catalog.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: No, I mean the text below that. I have edited the post to make clearer what I mean. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, got it.  Steps 1 and 2 look static.  Step 3 is in `config/README.md` and steps 4 and 5 appear to be configured (slightly) by the [.snakemake-workflow-catalog.yml](https://github.com/snakemake-workflows/rna-seq-star-deseq2/blob/master/.snakemake-workflow-catalog.yml)